# Erro ao instalar - NuGet - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Meu Nuget não estava conseguindo baixar nenhum pacote e eu não conseguia ver os pacotes instalados no  `Manager Package`, então pesquisei um pouco e resolvi desinstalar e instalar novamente.

O problema começa quando tento reinstalar o nuget, logo que começa a fazer o donwload eu recebo o  seguint erro:

> The extension could not be installed because of the following error:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server

Eu tentei

- [Limpar o HTTP-PROXY](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2289942/how-to-reset-your-internet-explorer-proxy-settings.)
- Tentei retirar a tag `<system.net></system.net>` do arquivo `devenv.exe.config`
- Deletar o `.suo`

Mas infelizmente nada resolveu, se alguém tiver alguma ideia de como resolver ficarei grato.

Comment: Cara, não precisava ter desinstalado nada, foi um problema na API.

Comment: Já conferiu em menu Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Source se existe o valor nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2) configurado? E se sim, você consegue acessar normalmente este endereço? Um XML será exibido.

Comment: Eu acabei de resolver, entrei no site nuget.org e baixei diretamente e instalei , agora esta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: @jbueno problema na API ?   baixei direto do nuget.org e funcionou, não sei porque  ocorreu este erro, gostaria de saber =/.

Comment: @WilliamCézar O que eu estou dizendo é que a API do nuget (apenas a versão 3) não estava funcionando domingo e ontem teve algumas falhas, por isso você não conseguia baixar nada.

Comment: @jbueno, ah entendi, vlw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver este erro baixando  direto do site do [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) e instalando manualmente.

Lembrando que a Api do Nuget estava instável na época em que tive este problema.